# Significance of @Produces, @GET, @Path and @QueryParam before function definition

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to java. I was looking the below code.

```
@Produces("text/xml")
@GET
@Path("/xml/search")
public Object searchXML(@QueryParam("query") String query,
        @QueryParam("granularity") String granularity) {
    return search(query, granularity);
}
```

I couldn't understand the uses of @Produces, @GET, @Path and @QueryParam before function definition in above code.
Can anybody put some light on this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those anotations are defined by [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services), a Standard for RESTful Web Services.

In the example above, it mean the method will handle a:

- GET request
- on path "/xml/search"
- and map the query argument "query" to String query argument,
- as well as the "granularity" to granularity
- the resulting content-type will be "text/xml"

(and it will probably call a custom marshaller for this)

(see [this page](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features) for a reference)

Comment: The url does not work anymore. Perhaps this is the same: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/6nisfjmk8/index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

A producer method is a method that generates an object that can then be injected.[Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkgkv.html)
When you want to inject an object that is not itself a bean
When the concrete type of the object to be injected may vary at runtime
When the object requires some custom initialization that the bean constructor does not perform

@GET: Transmits a representation of the resource identified by the URI to the client. The format might be HTML, plain text, JPEG, and so on. See How to Transmit a Representation of the Resource (@GET). [Link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=use%20of%20@get&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CE0QFjAE&url=http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/develop.htm&ei=TprvUJuEHoGHrAe86oD4CA&usg=AFQjCNGw3PH1USrab_Glkss18qk7sQqtIg&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.bmk)

@Path(param) : @PathParam is a parameter annotation which allows you to map variable URI path fragments into your method call. [Link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=use%20of%20@path&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CFEQFjAF&url=http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/_PathParam.html&ei=NpvvUL6pEo3JrAfCmoEI&usg=AFQjCNHyOfRFHclLffHm5ZexX-4qGKScnA&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.bmk&cad=rja)

can use @QueryParam annotation to inject URI query parameter into Java method [Link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=use%20of%20@queryparam&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/&ei=jJvvUKSrMIjRrQe6qoHQDw&usg=AFQjCNEfssODesa4KGpGhrmAVWXolfU30w&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.bmk&cad=rja)

Answer (score 0):

@Produces annotation is to specify the MIME media types of representations a resource can produce and send back to the client.here mediatype is an text rather xml can be recieved,

@GET is an HTTP Methods like  @PUT, @POST, @DELETE

@Path annotation's value is a relative URI path .In this the function call will be from service is through the path as `/xml/search/` to the function with the params.

@QueryParam is to extract query parameters from the Query component of the request URL, in this receives the param as strings from the URL .

[Document Reference](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/snapshot/jaxrs-resources.html#d4e111) [more info](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggnxo/index.html)